# Plot Magnitude Spectrum of Triangle Wave

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing, fft

I got a periodic triangle wave (pic. 1) and I need to plot its magnitude spectrum (like pic. 2) for different \tau values (\tau = T/2, \tau = T/4, \tau = T/16). Is there any way to do this in matplotlib? It seems that [scipy triangle function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html) doesn't even allow to define the triangle wave with "gaps". And [magnitude_spectrum](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.magnitude_spectrum.html) from matplotlib produces 'continuous' plot while I need 'discrete' one.

UPD: The question was previously about plotting the Fourier transform but I figured out that's probably not exactly what I wanted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on what exactly you would like to do. Are you trying to write a program that computes the fourier transform of a (finite) triangle wave and then plot it? Or are you trying to plot the analytic solution for the transform of a triangle wave for different values of tau and alpha? Please edit the question to clarify

Comment: Oh, I see that I misinterpreted. I thought they just wanted the plot

Comment: Sorry, clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

How is this?

```py
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def ξ(x, a, τ):
    return [a*max(0, e) for e in -signal.sawtooth(τ * np.pi * x, 0.5)]

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 400)
plt.plot(x, ξ(x, a=2, τ=1))  
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('ξ')
plt.title('Fourier Transform')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems this is the plot of the "half-triangle" wave function described by OP, but just called "Fourier transform" as title. I think OP wants the Fourier transform of this signal function, which I suppose will be a completely different plot

Comment: Yes, you're right. I decided to leave this answer here in case op was interested.

Comment: I think you have done almost a ll the work with this (OP just need to compute psd and plot) but it is a bit odd to title the plot as Fourier Transform. But as Pac0 points, the title should be "triangle wave/saw tooth"